# Can't send email with jasper report from jasper server

Tags: email, jasperserver

I am unable to send email with jasper report using jasper server. I tried the following configuration,
**js.quartz.properties**

```
report.scheduler.mail.sender.host=smtp.gmail.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.username=xxx@gmail.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.password=xxxx
report.scheduler.mail.sender.from=xxx@gmail.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.protocol=smtps
report.scheduler.mail.sender.port=465
```

Also tried this way too,

```
report.scheduler.mail.sender.host=smtp.gmail.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.username=xxx@gmail.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.password=xxxx
report.scheduler.mail.sender.from=xxx@gmail.com
report.scheduler.mail.sender.protocol=smtp
report.scheduler.mail.sender.port=587
```

**applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml**

```
<bean id="reportSchedulerMailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="${report.scheduler.mail.sender.host}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${report.scheduler.mail.sender.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${report.scheduler.mail.sender.password}"/>
        <property name="protocol" value="${report.scheduler.mail.sender.protocol}"/>
        <property name="port" value="${report.scheduler.mail.sender.port}"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                 <prop key="mail.smtps.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Also I have made **Allow less secure apps: ON** for my google account.
Given below is the stack trace shown in *View -->Messages*

```
Subject:
The job failed to execute. Review its parameters.

Date:
Today

Component:
Report Scheduler

Message:
Job: Test 6 (ID: 922871) Report unit: /Report/Daily_Collection_Report Quartz Job: ReportJobs.job_922871 Quartz Trigger: ReportJobs.trigger_922867_0 Exceptions: The job error notification was not completed. An error occurred while sending it. org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError v67sm3191899pfb.45 - gsmtp ; message exception details (1) are: Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError v67sm3191899pfb.45 - gsmtp at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1388) at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:959) at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:583) at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:416) at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340) at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:336) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJobMailNotificationImpl.sendMailNotification(ReportExecutionJobMailNotificationImpl.java:135) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.sendMailNotification(ReportExecutionJob.java:974) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.executeAndSendReport(ReportExecutionJob.java:570) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.execute(ReportExecutionJob.java:220) at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213) at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557) fail to send out alert mail notification org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError m19sm3330229pff.108 - gsmtp ; message exception details (1) are: Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError m19sm3330229pff.108 - gsmtp at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1388) at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:959) at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:583) at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:416) at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340) at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:336) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJobAlertImpl.sendAlertMail(ReportExecutionJobAlertImpl.java:102) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.sendAlertMail(ReportExecutionJob.java:615) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.executeAndSendReport(ReportExecutionJob.java:595) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.execute(ReportExecutionJob.java:220) at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213) at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
```

Please advice on how to configure jasper so that I can send emails.
Thank you!

Comment: Please, don't add irrelevant tag. Thanks!